# Unhashable type: 'list' error when trying to add m2m relationships dynamically using post_save in Django

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

My Content model has a many-to-many relationship to the Tag model. When I save a Content object, I want to add the relationships dynamically. Im doing this the following way.

```
def tag_content(obj):
    obj.tags.add([1,2,3])
    obj.is_tagged = True
    obj.save()
    return obj

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Content(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_tagged = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Content, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

@receiver(post_save, sender = Content)
def update_m2m_relationships_on_save(sender, **kwargs):
    if not kwargs['instance'].is_tagged:
        tag_content(kwargs['instance'])
```

Basically, when a Content object is saved, the receiver is used to call a post_save method which in turn calls the tag_content method to add the m2m relationships. However, I get this error:

```
TypeError
unhashable type: 'list'
```

It specifically references the .add() function. Any idea why I am getting this error? Any help is appreciated. Also, do note that I have Tag objects with ids = 1, 2, and 3 in database.

**EDIT**

Alright, I changed my tag_content to something like this:

```
def tag_content(obj):
    for tag in Tag.objects.all():
        print tag
        obj.tags.add(tag)
```

This is because the add() method takes in object instances, not ids. However, it still doesn't work :/ I get no error, but the relationships are simply not established.

This is especially weird since the print tag command works and prints out the tags. In other words, the function is being called. Any help please? Btw, I am running Django 1.9.8.

Comment: what version of Django are you running?

Comment: re: your edit, are you executing `obj.save()`? you did on the previous version

Comment: Yes I am executing the save method.

Comment: How are you checking to see whether the relationships are established? Your edited code should work.

Comment: By going into the admin panel. And yeah, I realize this should work, but for some reason, its simply not working :/

Comment: does adding tags manually in the [shell](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#shell) work?

Comment: Yep. If I call the method in shell, like say tag_content(content_instance), then it works perfectly.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the `Content` instance is saved and has and ID by the time it reaches your `tag_content`? I'm thinking it might not work when creating new `Content` but will when editing an existing one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [`add` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) you need actual models to be passed as args.

If you really want a list of models you need to unpack it, but you might as well pass the objs as arguments directly in this case.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot pass a list to `add()`, which is why you get the error. You either need to add one item at a time or expand the list into a series of arguments, e.g:

```
obj.tags.add(*[1,2,3]) # The * expands the list into the function arguments
```

This will still cause an error because you cannot pass IDs to `add()` - you have to pass `Tag` objects to it. So something like this would work:

```
# Get a list of Tag objects
tags_to_add = [Tag.objects.get(id=j) for j in [1, 2, 3]]
# Now pass this to the add() function:
obj.tags.add(*tags_to_add)
```